# Key sequences that are translated to ESC

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, escape

I understand from the FAQ that Escape is supposed to be the same as `C-[`: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Basic-keys.html

However, I could rebind `C-[` without any problems before I knew that. But if I try to bind `C-M-\"` it tells me that

```
Key sequence C-M-" starts with non-prefix key ESC
```

So I guess the wiki is outdated? In any case, I could spare the key, but when I try to use `M-\"` I get the same error message. So which one is it and can I use either one?

Comment: Your question is not clear: are you rebinding `C-[`? to what? and then rebinding ``C-M-\``? to what? What does "I could spare the key" mean? And when you say "I could rebind `C-[` without any problems before I knew that", does that mean that you cannot rebind it now? Please provide a complete recipe (starting from `emacs -Q`) to reproduce the problem.

Comment: ASCII character `ESC` is the *same character* as ASCII control character `C-[`. But as @NickD said, please specify what you're asking more clearly.